# UI utilizing QGraphicsSvgItem elements

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsview, qgraphicssvgitem

I'm hoping to consolidate a bunch of buttons for a QGraphicsView UI in a single svg file. I'm able to get the svg loaded into my graphics view. I can click and map the item at my mouse, but it's just the QGraphcisSvgItem. I'd hope to be able to find out which element was under the mouse in order to change opacity on hover, add unique functions for clicking each element, etc.

Any way to get the elementID under the mouse of an QGraphcicsSvgItem?

Comment: Digging a little deeper I'm thinking I could somehow parse the svg paths and create QPainterPaths from that?  Is that possible?

Comment: please share the .svg as sample

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.